# Zip file using tar on linux server

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to make a zip file out of some files but when I extract the zip I only get 1 file.

```
tar cfvz test.zip file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.jpg
```

And after I extract test.zip I only get a "test" file.The size of the zip size is ok, I just don't know how to make this work so that on extract I get the same files:"file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.jpg"

Comment: A `test` file, or a `test` folder?

Comment: Just a test file.

Comment: Odd. I have no clue.

Comment: do you confuse .zip and .gz on purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ tar -czvf test.tar.gz ./file1 ./file2 ...

$ tar -tzf test.tar.gz
./file1
./file2

# to extract do:
$ tar -xzf test.tar.gz
```

After passing `f` option you should give the filename of the archive you are creating.

Oh, and in case you are using `zip` to unzip the file, you wont get a directory but you will get a tarball instead. Tarball contains all your files. Use:

```
tar -xf test
```

And you should see all your files.

If you'd like to have *normal* zip files, use `zip` command instead of `tar`/`gz` tandem. Also it is a good practice to add correct file suffix:

- tar with gzip (i.e. `tar czvf ...`): filename.tar.gz
- tar with bzip2 (i.e. `tar cjvf ...`): filename.tar.bz2
- tar without compression (i.e. `tar cvf ...`): filename.tar

Comment: to create a tar.gz use:
`tar czvf file.tar.gz /folder`
to extract:
`tar xzvf file.tar.gz .`
sometimes it's better to use quotes "file1 file2 file3"...

Comment: @Thomas sure you can do it without `-` but who cares ;) works either way.

Comment: I need the .zip file.I've created some symbolic links and I'm trying to do the same thing using "zip --symlinks" like "tar -h " but it doesn't work.Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

First, even if you have named your compressed file `.zip`, it is not a ZIP file but a TAR & GZIP file, so the correct file extension to use would be `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`.

Now, what is the command you used to extract the compressed file?  If you used a ZIP utilities, it may have been confused by the extension and only uncompressed the file without untarring it.  That would explain why the result is a single file, which is actually a TAR file.  If you use an untar utility (or the command `tar -xf test`), you should get back all your file from within.

Comment: you are right.The only reason I used tar is because I haven't found a way to use zip with symbolic links.

Answer (score -1):

To extract the files you should do

```
tar xvfz test.zip
```

and by default all files will pop out from the path relative to where you are so if test.zip contained myfile.txt dir1/myfile.txt both files would come out the zip

Comment: Correct. Looks like OP is unzipping tarballs with something like winzip/unzip instead of tar/gz.